# Can I determine the order of the widgets in the gallery (Swift)?

Tags: swift, widget, widgetkit

The order of the widgets in the gallery seems to me arbitrary. Is there a way to arrange the WidgetExtensions in a certain order with Xcode or in Swift?

[image]

In my case I do have several targets where I have created different widgets.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Widgets are displayed in the same order in which you put them in the `WidgetBundle`:

```
@main
struct TestWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        FirstWidget() // will be displayed first...
        SecondWidget()
    }
}
```